# CSS Selector for higher order li

Tags: html, css

As you can see I had a difficult time expressing the question in the title.

I have a `ul` that contains `li`s which themselves contain a `ul` with it's own `li`s.

I would like to target *just* the first `li` elements and not the elements within the second `ul`.

If you look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fqbc4ud/) (or the code below), I would like to change item 1's color but not sub item 1's. Is that possible without attaching a class to the `li` elements?

```
<div class="foo">
    <ul>
        <li>
            item 1
            <ul>
                <li>sub item 1</li>
             </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>           
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so, use the [child combinators selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), which only selects a direct child.

At first glance you might use `ul>li`, but that will also select the second level list-items, since they're also a direct child of the list.

So you need to define a starting point, in this case the parent (div).

I now see that you already have the answer yourself. It however doesn't work in your fiddle since you don't declare a 'default' color. Which means that the second level list-item inherits the color of it's parent.

```
li {
    color: blue;
}
.foo>ul>li {
    color: red;
}
```

[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fqbc4ud/3/).

Answer (score 1):

will something like this help?

```
.foo ul li {
    color: red;
}
.foo ul li ul li {
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: The reason I don't like that method is because the first rule will apply to the sub li elements until I make the second rule, ya know? I don't want extra lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/6fqbc4ud/6/

```
:not(li) > ul > li  {
    color: red;
}

ul li{
    color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.foo  ul li { color: black; }
.foo  > ul > li { color: red; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fqbc4ud/)